# Return most frequent use value in a column without LIMIT

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been looking through forums, and I see most of the answers contains 
LIMIT, I just wonder how do you return most frequent value without LIMIT. Example: You don't know how many variable would have the highest value and you don't know the highest value. But you want to display all the variables with the highest values

So far my code is

```
SELECT b.column1, b.column2, count(a.column1)
FROM alphabet a
LEFT JOIN book b ON a.column1= b.column1
GROUP BY a.column1
ORDER BY count(a.column1) desc;
```

Is there a way to return most frequent value without using limit?

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh SQLiteStudio

Answer (score 0):

A general pattern to solve such problems is to compare a value (aggregated or not) to the maximum value selected in a subquery. The following query, for example, should work for you:

```
SELECT b.column1, count(a.column1)
FROM alphabet a
LEFT JOIN book b ON a.column1= b.column1
GROUP BY b.column1
having count(a.column1) = (select max(cnt) from (
   select count(a2.column1) as cnt
   from  alphabet a2
   group by a2.column1))
```

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work, having errors in "having count" section but I get the idea

Comment: Unfortunately sqlite does not support a `max` with a subquery, and it also does not support quantifier `ALL`. But a `select max(cnt) from (select count(*) as cnt ...)` should work. Adapted the answer accordingly.